# Overload Base Constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a class like this:

```
public class foo
{
    public foo(string a, string b) { ... }
}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
public class bar : foo
{
    public bar()
    {
        base = base("apple", "banana");
    }
}
```

Visual Studio yells at me saying:

```
'foo' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do. What do you mean by overloading a base constructor? What is the purpose of the assignment to `base`? Do you want to call a parameterized base constructor before the derived constructor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the way to do it:

```
public class foo
{
    public foo(string a, string b) { ... }
}

public class bar : foo
{
    public bar(): base("apple", "banana") // call base constructor
    {

    }
}
```

Reference : [Using Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite like this:

```
public bar() :
    base("apple", "banana");
{
}
```

Comment: Yes, without the explicit call to the base constuctor, the derived class default constructor will try to call the base default constructor, and there isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public class bar : foo
{
    public bar() : base("apple", "banana")
    {
    }
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following.  In essence you are telling the compiler which constructor to use as there is no default one available.

```
public class foo
{
    public foo(string a, string b) { }
}

public class bar : foo
{
    public bar()
        : base("apple", "banana")
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the bar constructor to call the base constructor correctly.

```
public class bar : foo 
{ 
  public bar() :  base("apple", "banana")
  { 
  }
}
```